# Can we use Angular 5 application in a access restricted region (Banking,financial, healthcare, insurance)

Tags: angular

We are creating an asp.net mvc application for one of our client. we decided to do the presentation layer in Angular 5.  Since we can use jquery locally, it is not required to have a Internet access what about Angular 5 ?

Can we use Angular 5 application in a access restricted region (Banking,financial, healthcare, insurance)? Will it download dependencies from Internet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you build your app, no internet connection is required and it can work offline as well as in intranet.